# Passing file contents through a bidirectional pipe

Tags: python, c++, unix, pipe

I'll start by briefly explaining my program then I'll move to my question. 
I created a bidirectional pipe that does the following:

1. The parent process passes a string value to the child process (in my program the string value is "TEST DATA")
2. The child process reads the passed data from its parent and executes a python file that simply attaches two strings together (the string received from the parent process "TEST DATA" with "CHILD PROCESS: ")
3. The attached strings are sent back to the parent process which simply prints them out.

   - after executing this program, the output will look like the following:

> parent process: CHILD PROCESS: TEST DATA

and these are my C++ and python program codes:

test.cc:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int writepipe[2] = {-1,-1};// parent -> child
  int readpipe[2] = {-1,-1};//child -> parent
  pid_t childpid;

  if(pipe(readpipe) < 0 || pipe(writepipe) < 0)
    {
      //cannot create a pipe
      printf("error creating pipe");
      exit(-1);
    }
#define PARENT_READ readpipe[0]
#define CHILD_WRITE readpipe[1]
#define CHILD_READ writepipe[0]
#define PARENT_WRITE writepipe[1]

  if((childpid=fork())<0)
    {
      //cannot fork child
      printf("cannot fork child");
      exit(-1);
    }
  else if (childpid==0)
    {//child process
      close(PARENT_WRITE);
      close(PARENT_READ);
      dup2(CHILD_READ,0); //read data from pipe instead of stdin
      dup2(CHILD_WRITE , 1);//write data to pipe instead of stdout
      system("python test.py");
      close(CHILD_READ);
      close(CHILD_WRITE);
    }
  else
    {
      close(CHILD_READ);
      close(CHILD_WRITE);
      //do parent stuff
      write(PARENT_WRITE,"TEST DATA\n",23);
      int count;
      char buffer [40];
      count=read(PARENT_READ,buffer,40);
      printf("parent process: %s",buffer);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

test.py:

```
import sys
data=sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write("CHILD PROCESS: "+data)
```

**My question is:**
I have a text file (lets call it test.txt) that contains few lines of data and I want to be able to use the previous code but instead of sending one string value (TEST DATA) I want to send the contents of the entire text file..
Any hints?

Comment: What is exactly giving you an issue here? If you know how to send the text, how is sending file different? Do you know how to read data from the file?

Comment: The "write" function only accepts string values as its second parameter. I'm not sure how to pass file contents to the child process @sergeyA Unless it's possible to read the file contents first then use a loop to send each line separately  ?

Comment: You nailed it! In a loop, you can read a string from the file, and than send this string through the pipe.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @sergeyA .. So I have to send the file contents line by line? isn't there anyway to send the entire file at once? for example, If the python code needs to read an entire text file in order to produce an output.. How could that be done?

Comment: In the C program, you have to create a buffer to read the file into and then send that to the pipe. If the buffer is smaller than the file, you need multiple reads. The pipe may not take the full write in one gulp so you may need multiple writes. This is usually done with an outer loop that reads some data and then an inner loop that writes the data... then repeat until the file transfer is done.

Comment: @tdelaney makes sense! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the C program, you have to create a buffer to read the file into and then send that to the pipe. If the buffer is smaller than the file, you need multiple reads. The pipe may not take the full write in one gulp so you may need multiple writes. This is usually done with an outer loop that reads some data and then an inner loop that writes the data... then repeat until the file transfer is done. – tdelaney